# Python3 find last occurrence string then write

Tags: python, list, object, python-3.x

I am trying to create a script that will add a zone to the end of named.conf if domain does not exist (last occurrence of the marker #--# and write to next line) . 
I appear to be caught in a paradox of list vs. file object. If I open as list, I can find my string but cannot write to the file without closing list object first which is not a good solution.
If I open the file as file object, I get an object error trying to use find

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "named.py", line 10, in <module>
    answer = mylist.find('#--#')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'
```

or

```
  File "named.py", line 12, in <module>
    f.write("   zone \""+name+"\" {\n")
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

What is the proper way to to open a file for search and editing in Python3?

```
import sys
import string
import os.path

name = input("Enter the domain to configure zone for? ")
#fd = open( "named.conf", 'w')
if os.path.lexists("named.conf"):
        with open('named.conf') as f:
                mylist = list(f)
                print(mylist)
                f.write("      zone \""+name+"\" {\n")
```

Comment: So what problem exactly do you see with your code? It looks correct to me. Also note that there is no such thing as "closing the list object" or "opening the file as a list"; what you do here is open the file and read its contents into a list. The list doesn't need to be closed.

Comment: code is missing. Where ` answer = mylist.find('#--#')`  in program??

Comment: you would first have to open for writing and reading, but even then you will have problems. where are you checking if the domain exists?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham because if it not there it needs to be added

Comment: @yole I added the corresponding error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is only open for reading so that is why you get the error, whether you use `in` or `==` depends on whether the line can contain the domain name or the line needs to be  equal to the domain name.

```
if os.path.lexists("named.conf"):  
    with open('named.conf') as f:
        found = False
        for line in f:
            # if domain is in the line break and end
            if name in line.rstrip():
                found = True
                break
    # if found is still False we did not find the domain
    # so open the file and append the domain name
    if not found:
        with open('named.conf', "a") as f:
            f.write("      zone \{}\ {\n".format(name))
```

To find the last occurrence of a line and write a line after:

```
if os.path.lexists("named.conf"):
        with open('named.conf') as f:
            position = -1
            for ind, line in enumerate(f):
                # if line is  #--#
                if "#--#" == line.rstrip():
                    # keep updating index so will point to last occurrence at the end
                    position = ind 
        if position != -1: # if we found at least one match
            with open('named.conf', "r+") as f:
                for ind, line in enumerate(f):
                    if ind == position: # find same line again
                        # write line and new line
                        f.write("{}{}\n".format(line,your_new_line))
                    else:
                        f.write(line)
```

Comment: I am stick stuck as to how to search and write i the same instance.  On line 10, if I need to write to a specific place in the file such as 'after the last occurrence of the string #--# (I need a file marker to update a dynamic file.)

Comment: use enumerate, get the index, reopen write the line at the index + what you want to insert. The newline will make sure it is written in the next line

Comment: @mine, added an example

Comment: final update: @Padraic Cunningham for anyone looking to do the same, your code works and does answer the question though the proper solution I discovered was to "include 'some.txt'" in named.conf and append to the end of that file any additional zone you want to add, vice butchering the named.conf directly and trying to do stuff in the middle of the file

Comment: @mine, to to be honest I have no idea what you mean,  how can you include `some.txt` in another file and add something to a file on a condition without checking if the line exists? Also  `open('named.conf', "a")` is appending to the file. You can read all the file into memory and just check the last line for a match but that is not an efficient way and won't work in cases where you have very large files. The "correct" way is to do it line by line as I have in my answer thus avoiding reading whole files into memory.

Comment: There is no infinite looping happening so I cannot see any way the code would hang,  have you put any print statements in to see what  is happening?

Comment: I never reach the first print('1') statement during execution. I have to kill -9 the process to unlock it  https://bpaste.net/show/cc797e5addfd

Comment: Have you actually entered anything into the console and pressed return?

Comment: I can't it freezes there. Can't enter anything.   o.0